Apache Beam and close the window when a condition is met
In Apache Beam, in Streaming job I can create an IntervalWindow that will last for 7 days.
IntervalWindow interval = new IntervalWindow(timestamp, Duration.standardDays(7));

But is there a way to automatically close the window when a certain condition is met, for example, when there are at least 4 messages in the window? Immediately after that, I would like to execute some logic and close the window without waiting for the 7 days to expire. Is this possible in Apache Beam, and if so, how?

You can't directly close a window early based on content in Apache Beam's built-in windowing.  Interval windows have a fixed duration once it is assigned. Probably the alternative way but more complex is using a custom WindowFn that tracks the number of elements assigned to each window and closes the window when the condition is met. This involves overriding the assignWindows and potentially other methods of the WindowFn interface.
